# Memory management in interface builder

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder

If I put a label in Interface Builder, and don't connect it with an IBOutlet, do I have a memory leak? Or does the system call dealloc itself?

Answer (score 2):

No, you won't have a leak. Without an IBOutlet, you are never directly calling `retain` on the object. Therefore the only thing that will be retaining the object is the view that the label is a subview of, because when you add a subview to a view, it calls retain. When the parent view is dealloced, it will call `release` on all of its subviews, which will dealloc the label.